# inspect.getmembers doesn't return member until a run a help()

Tags: python, python-inspect

`getmembers` from `inspect` doesn't return all the members. I am using this on a locally installed package, example code:

```
from inspect import getmembers, ismodule
import xyz
getmembers(xyz, ismodule)  # []
help('xyz.abc')
getmembers(xyz, ismodule)  # [('abc', <module xyz.abc ...>)]
help('xyz.lmn')
getmembers(xyz, ismodule)  # [('abc', <module xyz.abc ...>), ('lmn', <module xyz.lmn ...>)]
```

Why is this happening?
May be `help` is importing the module, but when I do a `import *` manually it doesn't work!

Example,

```
from inspect import getmembers, ismodule
from xyz import *
getmembers(xyz, ismodule)  # []
```

But yes when I do a `from xyz import abc` specifically then it works and returns `abc` module, but **how can I get all of them without running individual imports?**

Comment: `help('xyz.abc')` is likely importing `xyz,abc` to get its docstring.

Comment: @martineau right, I actually hadn't explained my question properly earlier.. updated it now.